# Sort array with duplicates by unique chunks

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want elements of that:

```
['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','4']
```

to be grouped into chunks with unique values, to make it look like that:

```
['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','2','3','3','3','3','3']
```

First "chunk" `'1','2','3','4'` contain all unique values without duplicates, second `'1','2','3'` etc.

---

The biggest problem is that my array is not combined from simple numbers, it is two-dimensional associative array, something like that:

```
[['id'=>'xd1c',...],['id'=>'ab2c',...],['id'=>'xd1c',...],['id'=>'xd1c',...],['id'=>'ab2c',...],['id'=>'xd1c',...],['id'=>'687d',...],...]
```

I don't have a lot of experience with algorythmics and advanced sorting and I feel a bit overwhelmed. Please if you could point me out in right direction with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$current = array('1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','4');
$new = array();
while(!empty($current)){
    foreach(array_keys(array_unique($current)) as $index){
        $new[] = $current[$index];
        unset($current[$index]);
    }
}
print_r($new);
```